# How to use root cause Exception type in Exception Router in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-integration

I am trying to handle the exception in my code . However the Messaging Exception wraps my customized exception thrown by the code.

Now I want to use the Exception router , and if the type is my customized exception , then i would like to send the message to queue a , else queue b.

Now the issue is, router is receiving the messaging exception object , hence it is not able to identify my exception , and is sending the message to queue b, while exception root cause is still my customized exception.

Router is given below:

```
 <int:exception-type-router input-channel="exceptionRouterChannel" 
     default-output-channel="unpersistedDest">
    <int:mapping exception-type=
                    "org.springframework.integration.MessageRejectedException"
        channel="validationErrorsDest" />
    <int:mapping exception-type=
                        "com.error.StaleMessageException"
        channel="discardDest" />
</int:exception-type-router>
```

Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no reason to `map` to messaging exceptions. `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter` does the loop for `cause.getCause()`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/router/ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter.java#L41.

So, you can map only for your exceptions.